# por que o g++ não compila o codigo que o visual studio compila?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

ja faz alguns projetos que testo e meu g++ não compila de jeito nenhum meus projetos do visual studio, erros que aparecem no g++ não existem no visual studio... alguem sabe o por que? e como voces acham que da pra resolver isso?

output do G++

```
Loader w Version Checker.cpp:35:2: error: 'b' does not name a type
}   w h i l e   ( P r o c e s s 3 2 N e x t ( S n a p S h o t ,   & p r o c E n t r y ) ) ;
```

^

Enquanto no visual studio...

[image: Tela do visual studio]

Comment: Não posso responder com certeza porque nunca usei o visual studio, mas pode ser algo relacionado com a linkagem das bilbiotecas. Talvez o visual studio faça isso automaticamente pra você com alguma biblioteca que você esteja usando, enquanto que pelo g++ você teria que fazer isso de maneira explícita.

Comment: pode ser tambem mas a minha solução tambem funcionou então não sei

Answer (score -1):

O visual studio usa uma plataforma para compilar diferente do g++, focada no windows a [MSVC : Microsoft C++ Compiler](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/03/07/use-any-c-compiler-with-visual-studio/)
enquanto o g++ usa a [Compilador c++ baseado na nix ou nix-based C++ compiler](https://www.cprogramming.com/g++.html)

Pra compilar um projeto c++ feito no visual studio teria que baixar o [Visual C++ 2015 Build Tools](http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools) e não o g++